# Code coverage with nUnit?

Tags: nunit, code-coverage

Is there a way to see the code coverage when using nUnit? I know there's such a feature in Visual Studio, but can you use it with nUnit or only with the built-in vs unit tests?

Comment: The question doesn't ask any recommendation for tools. It asks about nunit and visual studio code coverage features.

Comment: I've installed http://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework/ and VS2013 managed to show me my code coverage

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/). Now its commercial, but [version 1.5.8](http://www.ncover.com/download/current) (at the bottom of page, community edition) is still free and if you want to visualize it, then use [NCoverExplorer](http://www.kiwidude.com/blog/2006/01/ncoverexplorer-debut.html).

**EDIT:**

It's possible to wrap nUnit or mbUnit with Visual Studio code as well. [VSTS Code Coverage Runner](http://codecoveragerunner.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Just downloaded TestDriven.NET and apparently nCover is integrated in it. Very cool, the code coverage. Makes you see right away if you have things not covered in certain classes. Thx.

Comment: OpenCover is an open source code coverage tool https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover

Answer (score 19):

Visual Studio 2012 finally added support for third party unit test framework.

You can add frameworks using the Extension Manager and automatically "Code coverage" starts working with installed framework.

Code coverage is available only in Visual Studio Ultimate or Premium editions.

See my reply in [Does VS2010 Code Coverage support nUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665799/does-vs2010-code-coverage-support-nunit)

Answer (score 8):

PartCover is free and I've just blogged how to use it with NUnit
[See this link](http://blog.nomell.com)

Comment: PartCover is not supported anymore the "new" thing is OpenCover https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover

Answer (score 4):

See [SD C# Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html).  Comes with built-in visualization of test coverage data over your source code as well as summary reports.

Answer (score 4):

If you work at a company with a security-/saving-money-/hassle-employees- policy restricting your choice to VS2010 (Premium or Ultimate), see my answer to: 
[Running NUnit tests in Visual Studio 2010 with code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912878/running-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio-2010-with-code-coverage/18575469#18575469)

There, I refer to this other answer, but also give some more details than that:
[Does VS2010 Code Coverage support nUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665799/does-vs2010-code-coverage-support-nunit)

I know, copied/referring answers (esp. of others) are worth downvoting, but as I said, I give some details, which would've helped me quite a lot.