# Tests passed but code not coverage is 100% unit tests

Tags: nunit, vb.net-2010

I created an aspx page to test the methods of my class for a web service. 
When I run the project  all the objects created call methods and pass it around. 
All methods passed the test but the code is not covered 100%.
Can someone help me?

Comment: No, unfortunately nobody can help you. Help yourself by reading this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This means that there are function that are not tested. Maybe [Code coverage with nUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747649/code-coverage-with-nunit) can help.